# Fixing Google "above the fold"-Issue with my css

Tags: html, css, seo

i am trying to fix a problem related to my css. 
I checked it via google **Pagespeed Insights**.

It tells me there is a problem with my css-content "above the fold" which blocks rendering the page fast.

So i tried the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>//MINIFIED CSS</style>
<div class=mystyle>
// MY CONTENT
</div>
</body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print($base_url);?>css/style.css">
```

But i still have the same problem. Can anyone see whats causing it? From what i read my approach should fix this kind of problem.

Greetings

Comment: Hey! For starters you definitely don't want the <link> outside the <html> - browsers won't mind, but syntactically it doesn't make sense

Comment: You're miss-understanding the problem. Attempting to load _all_ your CSS in the footer won't help. You'll still be loading the CSS that is prevent the _"above the fold"_ content from rendering sooner. You need to separate your _"above the fold"_ CSS from the rest of your CSS. [Here is one approach on how to achieve this.](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/performance-rwd.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you guys, gonna change it now. I just applied what i found online, now im gonna do it right. Thank you so much!